# How to measure max. discharge rate for a battery?

Tags: batteries, safety

In datasheets of batteries one sometimes finds a max. safe discharge rate (i.e. max. safe current it can handle in an application). Sometimes it is also distinguished between short time and long time discharge rate.

What is the typical measurement procedure to get this number(s)?

I am interested in NiMh, LiPo and Li-Ion Batteries. Maybe for each type the procedure may be different.

Is it just measuring the temperature in dependence of discharge current and time? But if so, under which conditions and what are the temp limits etc.?

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the typical measurement procedure to get this number*

There is fundamentally no measurement procedure; it is a calculated factor possibly based on some destructive testing (at various temperatures) along with a decent margin for safety.

Comment: Could you describe the procedure more in detail? How is it calculated from which destructive testing setup?

Comment: @Julia I have no idea what to describe. All I know is that you should not retrospectively repeat what the manufacturer originally did because you will be in the area of significant health and safety problems.

Comment: I don't want to repeat the procedure, I am only interested to understand how it is done.